# check dropdown menu if matches

Tags: c#

Long story short: There are specific tags given (like Pop, Rock, Metal) and the User should write into a textbox and every time he adds a char the given tags are checked if one (or more) matches. At the moment I'm using a combobox with the following code:

```
    private void EnterComboBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> AllTags = new List<string>();

        AllTags.Add("Pop");

        if (AlleTags[0].ToLower().StartsWith(EnterComboBox.Text.ToLower()))
        {
            EnterComboBox.Items.Clear();
            EnterComboBox.Items.Add("Pop");
            EnterComboBox.DroppedDown = true;
        }
    }
```

this is working fine but the problem is, that after the first char entered the dropbox drops down and the entered text is marked and will be overwritten when a new char is entered. Any ideas how I could fix this? Every idea is welcome it doesn't have to be a combo box :)!

Edit:
After some more (detailed) research I realized I could explain it like this: Basically I want the combobox the behave like the search-bar from google. The users enters letters and in the dropdown menu are autocomplete suggestions

At the moment I solved it like this:
I placed a textbox in front of a combobox so that only the arrow of the combobx is visible and if you click on it you automatically write in the textbox.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        EingabeTextBox.AutoSize = false;
        EingabeTextBox.Size = new Size(243, 21);      //the size of the combobox is 260;21
    }

    private void EingabeTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EingabeComboBox.Items.Clear();

        List<string> AlleTags = new List<string>();

        AlleTags.Add("Example");

        if (AlleTags[0].ToLower().StartsWith(EingabeTextBox.Text.ToLower()))
        {
            EingabeComboBox.Items.Add(AlleTags[0]);
            EingabeComboBox.DroppedDown = true;
        }
    }
```

For me it would work like this. I hope I can help someone else with this too, but I am still open for any better ideas :)!

Comment: It look as if you were not entering the text in a TextBox as stated, but in the ComboBox itself.

Comment: Try to unselect the Combobox text when it is activated,
just take the editing cursor to the end.
If the entered text is gone, you could store it in some variable and get it again.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Yes currently I am writing the input into the combobox itself, but i am open to any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the ComboBox entries while typing into it obviously creates undesired interferences. Instead combine a TextBox and a ListBox.

```
private bool changing;

private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!changing) {
        changing = true;
        try {
            // manipulate entries in the ListBox
        } finally {
            changing = false;
        }
    }
}

private void ListBox_IndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!changing) {
        changing = true;
        try {
            // Put selected entry into TextBox
        } finally {
            changing = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The `changing` guard makes sure that the ListBox does not influence the TextBox while you are entering text into the TextBox and vice versa.

The try-finally ensures that the guard will be reset in any circumstances, even if an exception should occur.